# How do I know if a string is a cipher?

Tags: cryptography, ciphers

Hhello everyone. I have this string here:

```
697yqf3e3d9e3ej6d80y34y7jq
```

Is it a cipher? I've tried to decode it as a cryptogram. It didn't work. How do I know if something is a cipher?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean "ciphertext".

There's no way to know. First of all the string is simply too short to extract any information at all from it, without knowing it's purpose. And encryption-algo's have the exact job of obfuscating the meaning of the content. This is done by applying a transformation that maps the data to a (pseudo) random bitstring. And randomness is basically just the lack of possibilities to deduct any knowledge from data. This might be just some random string or a hash or some identifier or the start of an arbitrary file or in fact an encrypted string.

Comment: So how do I solve the "encrypted string"?

Comment: I got a hint. It has something to do with the keyboard.

Comment: @dattutbrus not at all, unless you know the algorithm that was used. And even in that case the algorithm has to be really trivial to make it crackable. The fact that you apparently don't even know what to expect as result from decrypting doesn't make this any simpler

Comment: I got the answer now. It's the Keyboard Shift cryptogram. Also because this is a step in a contest many people actually managed to solve this.

Comment: @dattutbrus well, if it's only a cryptogram you're entirely wrong on this site. This is a site for security-related topics, not solving some riddles. cryptograms aren't relevant for security-purposes. At least not in a form that is human-solvable.

Comment: Encryption is made to be "as unpredictable" as possible, - so, I mean, it would kinda break the purpose of encryption if it produces output (even, some small output) that says "I am encrypted" (Obviously, at some scenarios - you need to at least introduce  the usage of encryption, e.g on full disk encryption, on Linux, maybe to store like the hash or something - but when I say output I mean, if you pick e.g a random line at a random position, of a whole encrypted disk - this data needs to be unpredictable)

Answer (score 0):

You don't.

Randomness is a lack of information. This is exactly what crypto attempts to accomplish; turning information into something at appears to just be randomness.